# Join Custom Table With Admin / Sales / Order / View

Tags: adminhtml, sales-order

Basically i'm trying to add additional data's to sales -> order -> view page.

I have a custom table named 'additional_order_info' i want to join this table with 'sales_flat_order' using 'order_id'

So far i noted that below function under `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View.php` is responsible to get order information's like Ordered date, etc..

```
public function getOrder() {
    return Mage::registry('sales_order');
}
```

So is there way to join my custom table with other sales_order related tables ? So that i can display my custom values under every order view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vinoth,You can do this by event and observer. According to magento system,**there are  two event fire on every collection load.**
One is collection load before and other is  collection load  after

Functionality,you can check at  on class `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract`

### Event on collection load before:

```
  protected function _beforeLoad()
    {
        parent::_beforeLoad();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('core_collection_abstract_load_before', array('collection' => $this));
        if ($this->_eventPrefix && $this->_eventObject) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_before', array(
                $this->_eventObject => $this
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

### Event on collection load after:

```
protected function _afterLoad()
    {
        parent::_afterLoad();
        foreach ($this->_items as $item) {
            $item->setOrigData();
            if ($this->_resetItemsDataChanged) {
                $item->setDataChanges(false);
            }
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent('core_collection_abstract_load_after', array('collection' => $this));
        if ($this->_eventPrefix && $this->_eventObject) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_load_after', array(
                $this->_eventObject => $this
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

**Now if we add the custom table  on basic of two event then it can fulfill yours requirement**

Basically on the sales order collection load event we can add your custom table.Just Order grid load from `sales/order_grid_collection`.This collection

collection these events are `sales_order_grid_collection_load_before` and `sales_order_grid_collection_load_after`. If we add custom table using joinLeft then it would be working good.

**Example:**

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
            <observers>
                <amit_sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
                    <class>Yourmodulem modelPrefix/observer</class>
                    <method>addmycustomtable</method>
                </amit_sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

**Observer code:**

```
<?php class MyNameSpace_Mymodule_Model_Observer
public function addmycustomtable(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(array('v' => 'additional_order_info'),
                        'main_table.entity_id = v.order_id',
                        array('*'));
}
}
```